# Lumen Blade result to array gives empty value

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, lumen

When I put the following code in my controller in Lumen it returns an empty value for the 'info' key, which should contain the Blade template:

```
$return = array();

$return['cities'] = $cities;
$return['info'] = view('popup/dialog')->with('result',$result);

return $return;
```

This returns the following

```
{"cities":["Den Helder"],"info":{}}
```

But when I only return the 'info' value, it will show the Blade template

```
return $return['info'];
```

I'm using this implementation in an websocket environment. I want to keep the websocket calls to a minimum. So it would be great to return the contents of the template, within the dataset.

Hope you can help.

Offtopic: I'm reading for a couple of years on this site, but this is my first post. If I'm doing something wrong, please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `render()` method to generate the HTML content of you view.

This should work:

```
$return['info'] = view('popup/dialog')->with('result',$result)->render();
```

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/View/View.html#method_render

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!